# Error in kubeless installation

Tags: kubernetes

I am tryng to install Kubeless on Kubernetes.  When I ran `kubectl get pods -n kubeless` , I gove this output:

```
NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-0                               0/1       Pending   0          7m
kubeless-controller-b54bc9db6-fl276   0/1       Pending   0          7m
zoo-0                                 0/1       Pending   0          7m
```

I waited some minutes and ran it again but status won't change.
How can I fixed it and install Kubeless?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't meet this problem while installing. but here are some advice I could support for you:

1. Check Kubeless troubleshooting guide

> Maybe following site will help you: [Kafka and Zookeeper Persistent Volume creation](https://kubeless.io/docs/troubleshooting/)

2. Check events of pending pods

> kubectl describe pod kubeless-controller-b54bc9db6-fl276 -n kubeless

3. Check logs of pending pods

> kubectl logs kubeless-controller-b54bc9db6-fl276 -n kubeless

4. If still cannot find any helpful message from logs, maybe you should debug with docker inside

> docker logs **[container with your pod]**

Hope upper tips could help you.